# Changes needs to deploy spring saml as an standalone service

Tags: spring, saml

Currently I am having a j2ee(non spring) application. I want to integrate SAML support to my application. For this I am deploying spring saml example as separate service and trying to make a rest api call, but it is redirecting the call to idp discovery page since there is no active session. So what necessary changes I need to make to run Spring SAML as a standalone service?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up a connection between your spring app to a functional IdP? Also, is your j2ee application web based?

I'll assume your app is web based. If your spring app works as expected, you can have a form in your app like this:

```
<form action="[url to your spring app]/saml/login?disco=true" method="GET">
    <input type="radio" name="idp" id="idp1" value="[path to your idp]">
    <label for="idp1">My IdP</label>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Start single sign-on">
</form>
```

The html is from running this page: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp

And modify the action link and IdP address to your configurations.

Then, by submitting the form, you have send a request to your spring app to log into the IdP you specified. Once you are logged in, you should be redirected to your spring app. There you can do a redirect to your own app with necessary authentication information.

I am not sure how secure this implementation would be. An optimal solution for production would still be having SAML authentication method built into your app.